# Vedic Chanting Rudram - Beginning verses?

Tags: shiva, vedic-chanting

Hari Om,

What is traditionally chanted before and after Rudram (Namakam & Chamakam)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before starting reciting Sri Rudram the LaghunyAsa is recited and the NyAsas are performed.

**LaghunyAsa:**

Note: NyAsa simply means to implant God principle in our own bodies. So, first we ourselves become God and then we worship him after being fully divinised. This is basically the idea behind the performance NyAsa.

LaghunyAsa begins with a DhyAnam (Meditative verse).

And, the DhyAnam begins with the following verse:

> AthAtmanam shivAtmAnam srirudrarupam dhyAyet|
>
> ......
>
> One should meditate on the form of Sri Rudra who is the self (Atma)
>   and the essence of happiness.

It then continues and finally ends with the following verse:

> Sarva vyApinam ishAnam rudram vai vishvarupinam evam |
>  DhyAtvA
>   dvijah samyak tato yajanam arabhet ||
>
> ...........
>
> He, Rudra, the Lord, has a form which envelops everything. After
>   having meditated on this God of perfection, the yajamana begins his
>   yajna (or worship).

Now, they do the NyAsas which goes like this:

> Prajanane brahma tishthatu (He establishes BrahmA in the source or in
>   the genitals).
>
> PAdyoh vishnuh tishthatu (Establishes Vishnu in the feet).
>
> Hastayoh harah tishthatu (Establishes Hara in the hands).
>
> BAhvoh indrah tishthatu (Establishes Indra in the arms).
>
> Jathare agnih tishthatu (Establishes Agni in the stomach).
>
> Hrdaye shivah tishthatu (Establishes Shiva in the heart).

This goes on till the 31st verse, where they say:

> Sarveshu angeshu sarvA devatA yathAsthAnam tishthantu. (Let all the
>   deities be established in their appropriate places in the subtle
>   body).
>
> MAm rakshantu (May they all protect me). **31**

NyAsa still continues with:

> vAyuh me prane shritah prAno hrdaye hrdayam mayi ( VAyu is lodged in
>   my PrAna; PrAna in the heart; heart in me.)

and many other similar verses.

Till the 49th verse NyAsa continues. Then, in the 50th verse, ViniyogAha for Sri Rudram is chanted as follows:

> Asya shri rudrAdhyAyaprashnamahAmantrasya aghora rshih, anushtup
>   chandah sankarshanamurtisvarupa yo asau Adityah paramapurushah sa esha
>   rudro devatA ||
>
> ...........
>
> For this great mantra of Rudra-adyaya, the rishi is Aghora (KAnva),
>   the metre is Anushtuph; He has the form of Sankarshana. The Supreme
>   Person beyond and great Sun are same as Rudra. **51**
>
> Namah shivAya iti bijam, shivatarAya iti shaktih, mahAdevAya iti
>   kilakam, Sri sAmbasadAshiva prasAda sidhyarthe jape viniyogah ||
>
> ...........
>
> Namaha shivAya is the seed, ShivatarAya is the energy, MahAdeva is the
>   linchpin,; The japa is done as an offering to Shri SAmba SadAshiva for
>   obtaining his (or their) grace. **55**

From here on starts Kara (hands), Anga (limb) and Hrdaya (heart) NyAsas.

This is done to divinise the fingers, hands, heart and all-body.

> OM agnihotratmane angushthabhyAm namaha | (Salutations to the thumbs
>   that embody Agnihotra). 
>   **56**

and so on. Along with chanting the mantras, certain postures and hand movements, Mudras are also to be performed, which one who has learned Sri Rudram from the teacher will know.

This HridyAdi NyAsa ends with:

> bhurbhuvahsuvarom iti digvandaha ( By bhur bhuvah svah, all the
>   quarters are secured) **68**

Then starts the DhyAnam for Sri Rudra:

> ApAtAla nabhah sthalAnta bhuvana brahmandam avisphurat jyotih sphAtika
>   linga mauli vilasat purnendu vAntAmri taih ......   murtibhedA rudrAh
>   shri rudrasukta prakatita vibhavA nah prayachchantu saukhyam ||
>   (incomplete-not all verse given)
>
> ............
>
> During japa with mantras of Shiva, the wise person (Vipra) meditates
>   on Rudra, who envelops all the worlds (BrahmAnda) from the lowest
>   world to the highest heaven ....  Who has the poison in the thoraot,
>   who has a Trishula in his hand, who has three-eyes, who is decorated
>   with the RudrAksha beads, who grants peace and who is beyond form
>   (Mutibheda).

Then they chant a mantra for Lord Ganapati, who is the first to be worshipped in every Hindu traditions. And then a ShAnti mantra is recited.

Now, the Sri Rudram recitation starts as usual from "Namaste rudra manyava uto ta ishave namaha". After finishing Namakam, the Chamakam is recited.

Then, Shiva Sankalpa mantras are usually recited to finish things off.

**Shiva Sankalpa mantras:**

These 6 mantras appear in the 34th AdhyAya of the VAjasaneyi SamhitA of the Shukla Yajur Veda and also in Khila portion of Rig Veda. They are all Rik mantras in the Trishtubh metre.

> YajjAgrato duram udaiti daivam tadu suptasya tathaivaiti ( The Divine
>   One, that wanders far off from the wakeful and likewise in the sleep
>   too) **1**..... SushArathirashvAn iva yanmanushyAn ( May that in which
>   guides men like a good charioteer)... Hritpratishtham yadajiram
>   javishtham (That which abides in the heart, most swift and active),
>   Tanme manah shivasankalpam astu (May that my mind aspire towards Shiva)
>   **6**. 
>   (Incomplete-Not all mantras given)

Comment: Very well compiled answer. Good one Rickross

Comment: Very good compilation. Thank you.

Comment: @SanatanaDhara thanks