# Siva sankalpa mantra meanings

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, mantras, yajur-veda

I'm interested to know the meaning of Siva sankalpa mantras. In particular the following two mantras:

एका च दश शतं च सहस्रं चायुतं च 
नियुतं च प्रयुतं चार्बुदं च नयर्बुदं च तन्मे मनः शिव संकल्पमस्तु

य पञ्चपञ्चा दशतं शतं च सहस्रं च नियुतं न्यर्बुदं च ।
ते यज्ञचित्तेष्टकात्तं शरीरं तन्मे मनः शिव संकल्पमस्तु ।।

Comment: Don't remove scripture and vedas tags from questions.Nobody is authorised to make unwanted corrections in tags.And without OP's approval. Some specific users are removing these Tags just for personal   or sectarian reason. If you cant earn badges in  this TAG leave the TAgs alone.@Sarvabhouma.

Comment: I have a book that has these Shiva Sankalpa Mantras. It has only a collection of 6 Mantras. These Mantras you mentioned are not there. I am not sure where's the problem

Comment: @SwiftPushkar That is wrong. Persons with edit privileges can do that. The question is not about a scripture. If yes, what is the scripture mentioned in the question? If the question is not about Vedas and it doesn't talk about scripture, what is the need of them? About scripture tag, there are already posts on meta. Read them. Don't be immature about badges and privileges, I got all of them.

Comment: @Rickross - Yes , these mantras are not there, I am also waiting to post the answer. But looking for variants.

Comment: Ok @SwiftPushkar yes these are not there in my book.

Comment: @Rickross It's there in [Tezz's Book](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18856/277) given by Sayana!

Comment: Ok @Pandya He is quoting from Khila of RigVeda. The book that I have is however having only the 6 Mantras that are found in the Vajasaneyi Samhita.

Comment: @Rickross I think it's from Asvalayana Samhita, btw, I've just updated the answer.

Comment: No it's from VS only see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/vedic-chanting-rudram-beginning-verses/22379#22379 @Pandya

Answer (score 8):

The mantras you quoted are usually not found in Shiva Sankalpa Suktam of Shukla Yajurveda. According to [Tezz's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18856/277), they are present in Khilani section (khilani are group of Suktas present or found in one Shakha of Veda but not presnet/found in another Shakha) of Rigveda.

English translation to the Khila Sutras (7-27) by Swami Veda Bharati can be found from [here](http://ahymsin.org/main/swami-veda-bharati/shiva-sankalpa-sukta.html) (scroll-down to bottom or visit [this](http://www.swamivedablog.org/shiva-sankalpa-sukta-%E2%80%93-7/)).

Quoting the 2<sup>nd</sup> mantra mentioned in question:

> य पञ्चपञ्चा दशतं शतं च सहस्रं च नियुतं न्यर्बुदं च ।
>   ते यज्ञचित्तेष्टकात्तं शरीरं तन्मे मनः शिव संकल्पमस्तु ।।
>
> The five, fifty, hundred, thousand, million, billion are the bricks of the fire altar that the body is composed of. It is all of the mind. May such my mind be of beautiful and divine resolves, filled with Shiva-thoughts.

Though I have not found the English translation of 1<sup>st</sup> Mantra, however found one Mantra in Shukla Yajurveda Adhyaya 13 which includes the 1<sup>st</sup> Mantra you quoted.

[Sanskrit Mantra](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E2%80%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AD)

> 17.2
>   इमा मे ऽ अग्न ऽ इष्टका धेनवः सन्त्व् **एका च दश च दश च शतं च शतं च सहस्रं च सहस्रं चायुतं चायुतं च नियुतं च नियुतं च प्रयुतं चार्बुदं च न्यर्बुदम्̐** समुद्रश् च मध्यं चान्तश् च परार्धश् चैता मे ऽ अग्न इष्टका धेनवः सन्त्व् अमुत्रामुष्मिंल् लोके ॥

[English translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk17.htm):

> 2 O Agni, may these bricks be mine own milch kine: one, and
>   ten, and ten tens, a hundred, and ten hundreds, a thousand,
>   and ten thousand a myriad, and a hundred thousand,
>   and a million, and a hundred millions, and an ocean middle
>   and end, and a hundred thousand millions, and a billion.
>   May these bricks be mine own milch-kine in yonder world
>   and in this world.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pandya for elaborate answer. I agree with your answer that Shiva Sankalpa Suktam contains only 6 mantras and both mentioned by me are not part of that Suktam. But they are part of Khila Suktam by Rigveda.

Comment: @NatarajMaddirala Yes, they are part of Khila Sukta of Rigveda.

Comment: @NatarajMaddirala if you're satisfied with answer, consider to tick on [accept button](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) Thanks.