# Is it mandatory to chant laghunyasam before chanting Sri Rudram?

Tags: shiva, rituals, vedic-chanting, rudram

I would like to know Is it mandatory to chant laghunyasam before chanting Sri Rudram?

Comment: Related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/vedic-chanting-rudram-beginning-verses/22379#22379

Comment: Generally Nyasa is done to make ourselves divinised so that the chant is more effective.